# parsing the response from xml

Tags: android, web-services, parsing, response

I am new to webservices and I want to parse this xml and store the response(String val) in a local variable. how can I do this? plz some one post the code snippet for this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
      <RegisterUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <RegisterUserResult>string</RegisterUserResult>
      </RegisterUserResponse>
    </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many parsing technique available in Android itself: [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), DOM Parser and [SAXParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html). You can implement any.

Here are the best examples to learn about XML Parsing: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/

Otherwise, you should try to Google with this link: http://bit.ly/j1j12x

Comment: The link `http:// bit.ly/j1j12x` is dead, and not archived.